# Presto hash / checksum computed over the entire table

Tags: sql, presto

Working (for the first time, I must admit) with AWS Athena and trying to verify data integrity of QA tables that are supposed to be identical to Production. Both environments are totally isolated, so there is no way of using any conventional SQL techniques involving joins, unions, Except clauses etc.
I guess comparing checksums is my best bet. However, while Presto documentation includes a number of hash and checksum functions, none of them seems to be applicable for the entire table. Your recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

With [`checksum`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#checksum) you can compute an order-insensitive checksum of every column. With [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) + again [`checksum`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#checksum) you can combine this column-level checksums into single table-level checksum.

Working example:

```
presto> with column_checksums as (
     ->     select array[
     ->         checksum(nationkey),
     ->         checksum(name),
     ->         checksum(regionkey) ] checksums
     ->     from tpch.tiny.nation
     -> )
     -> select checksum(cs) as table_checksum
     -> from column_checksums
     -> cross join unnest(column_checksums.checksums) as x(cs);

     table_checksum
-------------------------
 64 ce 66 7a 9a 78 9a 7b
(1 row)
```